# using .hover over an <li> to change colors, and target certain <li> in <ul>

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a newbie to jQuery, and am trying to have a certain `li` selected within a `ul` using the `.hover()` class, and make it so a `mouseOver` will have my selected `li` change to a random, predefined color:

I've got some of it working, mainly the random colors, except it isn't a `mouseOver`, and I do not know how to apply this to `.hover()`

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var color = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF00FF', "#00FFFF", 
               "#C0C0C0"];
  var random_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
  $('ul li a').css('color', random_color);
});
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation with a [working example of jQuery Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)?

Comment: jQuery has lots of [mouse events it can handle](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

Comment: i know it works kind of like

$( "li.fade" ).hover(function() {
$( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
$( this ).fadeIn( 500 );
});
</script>

where 'this' is your target selector, and i'd want to use ul li a for <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>

with mouseEnter, i'd want a color to randomly appear over the element, and turn back to white with the mouseLeave...

can I do this with fadeIn and fadeOut?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to store the current color so you can reset it when it leaves. Then you can use the jquery hover function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var color = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF00FF', "#00FFFF", 
               "#C0C0C0"];
   var random_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];

   /* create variable with current color */
   var orig_color = $('ul li a').css('color'); 

   $('ul li a').hover(
      function(){ 
         /* function executes on mouse enter */
         $(this).css('color', random_color);
     }, function() {
         /* function executes on mouse leave */
         $(this).css('color', orig_color);

     });
});
```

Comment: this is the closest to what I need, thanks so much! now i'm trying to use parent-child selectors to individually target the list's and anchors within the unordered list....but I think I do not grasp the :nth-child(2) idea, cause it is not working for me, haha

Comment: Haven an example somewhere of exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it. I added few more comments to the fiddle. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/r693J/)

```
function generate_random_color() {
var color = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF00FF', "#00FFFF", "#C0C0C0"];
  var random_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
   return random_color;

}
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul li').hover(function(){
        /* on mouse over it will change to a random background */
        $(this).css('background', generate_random_color);
    }, function(){
        /* on mouse leave it will change to a white background */
        $(this).css('background', '#fff'); 
    });
});
```